# One-tuples versus scalar elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, soft-question, proof-explanation

The context for this question is a specific theorem in Rudin's book. I'm fine with the proof, but I think there are some slight notational abuses which, while ultimately not a huge deal, I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around. The theorem is:

> Let $A$ be a countable set and $B_n = \{(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \mid a_i \in A\}$. Then $B_n$ is countable.

Rudin proceeds by induction and claims $B_1 = A$. I'm not certain that's the case, since I don't know if a "one-tuple" is the same as an element of $A$, which is likely a scalar. It's surely a natural identification, sending, say, $a \mapsto (a)$, but are these, truly, "the same thing?"

Similarly, when he goes on to prove the inductive step, after assuming inductively that $B_{n-1}$ is countable, he argues $B_n = \{(b, a) \mid b \in B_{n-1}, a \in A\}$. That doesn't seem completely right to me, as this isn't an $n$-tuple, but a two-tuple containing an $(n-1)$-tuple and the element $a$. Surely it's in bijection with $B_n$: I can just "flatten out" the tuple into an $n$-tuple and get a bijection. But it seems to me these aren't exactly the same thing.

Am I correct to think this is an abuse of notation, akin to saying $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: As far as sets are concerned, a bijection is as close to "the same thing" as you are going to get.  Ok, maybe a "natural bijection", which is certainly on offer here.

Comment: I don't think I've seen a distinction between $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ before. What definitions make them different?

Comment: @aschepler Sorry, that should just be $A$. I'll fix it.

Comment: @aschepler I think $\mathbb{R}^2$ was probably a bad example. I've seen this described as the set of maps from $\{0,1\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, though a better example is, say, $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^3$ versus $\mathbb{R}^5$. The former is a two-tuple whose elements are a two-tuple and a three-tuple, and the latter is a set of five-tuples.

Comment: I do think Rudin is implicitly utilizing Definition 2.3 in this proof. Put another way, instead of writing '... is bijective to ...' ad nauseam he is instead writing ...=... .

Comment: It could also matter if you and/or Rudin have a specific technical definition of $n$-tuple, or if we're just talking about tuples in a metalogic sense, with commonly understood properties and behaviors.

Comment: If Rudin *defines* $(x) := x$ and inductively defines $(x_1, \dots, x_n) := ((x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}), x_n)$ for $n > 2$, then his statements that trouble you are exactly true. But more generally, I counsel you to stop getting disturbed when someone says that two things that are natually isomorphic are equal. The existense of a natural isomorphism tells us that the two objects do not differ in any way that is of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to question that line of reasoning from Rudin, it is indeed an abuse of notation. It would have been more rigorous to give a definition of an $n$-tuple and to discuss the difference (or the sameness) between $a$ and $(a)$ as well as between $A^k\times A$ and $A^{k+1}$.

This is how Tao has done in his Analysis book:

[image]